# Pageable sorting with specifications returns duplicated results

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have a Service entity that has a field Jobs which has Job entity in a ManyToMany relationship.

Filtering, sorting and pagination works perfectly, but the only problem is sorting by Jobs.

When I send a request to `/serviceslist?sort=jobs&sortDir=asc` I get duplicate results for each Service that has multiple jobs connected to it. To be more specific, if a Service has 4 jobs, the service gets returned 4 times and so on.

I think I should use groupBy, but how would I implement groupBy in my service below?

Service:

```
public Page<com.bitweb.syda.data.entity.service.Service> getServicesList(ServiceListRequest request, Pageable pageable) {
        Specification<com.bitweb.syda.data.entity.service.Service> spec = where(null);

        if (request.getSearch() != null) spec = spec.and(search(request.getSearch()));
        if (request.getName() != null) spec = spec.and(name(request.getName()));
        if (request.getJobs() != null) spec = spec.and(hasJobs(request.getJobs()));
        if (request.getNeedsPatrol() != null) spec = spec.and(needsPatrol(request.getNeedsPatrol()));

        return serviceRepository.findAll(spec, pageable);
    }
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/serviceslist", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Page<ServiceResponse> getServicesList(
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") Integer size,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String search,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String name,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String jobs,
            @RequestParam(required = false) Boolean needsPatrol,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "createTime") String sort,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "asc") String sortDir
    ) {

        ServiceListRequest request = new ServiceListRequest(search, name, jobs, needsPatrol);

        Sort.Direction direction;

        if (sortDir.equals("asc")) {
            direction = Sort.Direction.ASC;
        } else {
            direction = Sort.Direction.DESC;
        }

        return serviceService.getServicesList(request, of(page, size, direction, sort))
                .map(ServiceResponse::new);
    }
```

Here are some examples what I've tried already:

```
public Page<com.bitweb.syda.data.entity.service.Service> getServicesList(ServiceListRequest request, Pageable pageable) {
        Specification<com.bitweb.syda.data.entity.service.Service> spec = (root, query, builder) -> {
            //you can do any check here if you want with the join and check all the search parameters here if you want
            //Join<Object, Object> jobs = root.join("jobs");
            // also set query to get distinct values
            query.distinct(true);
            return null;
        };

    if (request.getSearch() != null) spec = spec.and(search(request.getSearch()));
    if (request.getName() != null) spec = spec.and(name(request.getName()));
    if (request.getJobs() != null) spec = spec.and(hasJobs(request.getJobs()));
    if (request.getNeedsPatrol() != null) spec = spec.and(needsPatrol(request.getNeedsPatrol()));

    return serviceRepository.findAll(spec, pageable);
}
```

After trying this everything works as expected, but sorting by jobs gives me this error:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
  Position: 652
```

I'm not very proficient with SQL and Criteria API and I don't know what I could do to fix this.

When using `query.groupBy(root);` instead of distinct, I get this error:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: column "job4_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 780
```

Comment: What is the purpose of sorting by jobs, as it's a collection?

Comment: Here is an answer to the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53549880/1458562